# Blue screen with Windows 7 and atikmpag.sys

Tags: windows-7, boot-camp

I'm running Boot Camp on a brand new [27-inch iMac.](http://www.apple.com/imac/specs.html) Twice in the last week I've seen a blue screen citing atikmpag.sys. I think both times I was watching video online.

What gives?

Comment: atikmpag.sys is an ATI driver. I would simply updated it. read this took me 5 seconds to find doing a google search http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/blue-screen-error-with-atikmpagsys-in-windows-7/5f0aebb6-b9b6-4a5d-a622-97c62dbb3d66

Comment: What's done on your side?

Comment: I've googled and attempted updating the driver. The driver refused to update, and I think it's because of Boot Camp.